# Why does shell:windows in RUN(win + R) open up Windows directory?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, shell, cmd.exe

- Is this a Run(Win+R)-only thing? It doesn't do anything in cmd.
- What else can I do with this syntax/command?
- Where can I find documentation for this?
- Is this a windows 10 feature? Does it work on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2013/02/13/windows-shell-commands.aspx) that I found,

> Windows shell: commands are like environment variables on steroids.

Located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions`, you can find the complete list of shell commands available on your system.

i.e.

```
shell:system        -> system32
shell:programfiles  -> program files
shell:user pinned   -> quick launch
```

Just verified working on Windows7, Windows8, and windows 10.